# Implementation stack using switch case and while loop using C language

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I have written the following program to implement PUSH and POP operations in the stack in such a way that the program will execute till the user choose to exit. Users can perform PUSH, POP, and display the stack in a single execution. But after the execution of the program when I choose the option (1/2/3/4) in console windows, I get executed with an infinite output. So, what modification should I done in the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int maxsize, item;
int top = -1;
int ch;

int is_stack_empty ();
int is_stack_full ();
int push (int[]);
int pop (int[]);
int display (int[]);

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the size of stack: ");
    scanf("%d", &maxsize);
    
    int stack[maxsize];
     
    printf("\n 1. PUSH"); 
    printf("\n 2. POP"); 
    printf("\n 3. Display"); 
    printf("\n 4. Exit");
    
    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    
    while (1)
    {
        switch (ch) 
        {
            case 1:
            push (stack);
            break;
            case 2:
            pop (stack);
            break;
            case 3:
            display (stack);
            break;
            case 4:
            exit(1);
            break;
            default:
            printf("\nError! please select correct option");
        
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int display (int s[])
{ 
    printf("\nThe created stack is :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", s[i]);
    }
}

int is_stack_empty ()
{
    if (top == -1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int is_stack_full ()
{
    if (top == maxsize-1)
        return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}

int push (int s[])
{
    if(!is_stack_full())
    {
        printf("\nEnter the element of STACK[%d]: ", top+1);
        scanf("%d", &item);
        
        top = top + 1;
        s[top] = item;
    }
    else
    printf("\nError: Overflow! Stack is full! Couldn't perform PUSH operation.");
}

int pop (int s[])
{
    if(!is_stack_empty())
    {
        printf("\nPopped element is %d", s[top]);
        top = top - 1;
    }
    else
        printf("\nError: Underflow! Stack is empty! Couldn't perform POP operation.");
}
```

Comment: Is it intentional that you read the input value `ch` only once before entering the `while(1)` loop?

Comment: Unrelated, but very first thing that just jumps into my eyes: All global variables. You won't ever be able to create more than one stack at the same time. Better: Pack all those variables into a `struct` and let every function now operating on the globals accept a pointer to this struct as first parameter. This way you can handle more than one stack e.g. as `int is_stack_empty(struct stack* s) { return s->top == -1; }`.

Comment: And for the code style: *All* comparison operations are guaranteed by the standard to return either 0 or 1 – so no need for `if(comparison) return 1; else return 0;`, instead just have `return comparison;`, that's much better style. And if some general condition might return something different then again rather have `return general_condition != 0;` instead of `if(general_condition) return 1; else return 0;` (or: `!= NULL` for pointers, alternatively `!!pointer`; `== 0`/`!pointer` for the opposite test).

Comment: Not producing infinite output, still an error: If `-1` as `top` represents the empty stack then you need to iterate up to `i <= top` for displaying the entire stack (with `<` you skip last element). Better, though: Let `0` represent the empty stack, and rename `top` to `size` or similar. Then you actually can and should make `size` and *unsigned* type as negative sizes are meaningless anyway. Correct type for specifying such sizes actually is `size_t` from `stddef.h`...

Comment: All of `push`, `pop` and `display` specify `int` as return type but don't return anything. That's an error and yields undefined behaviour as soon as you at any time evaluate the return value (in contrast to C++ where not returning anything *always* yields undefined behaviour with exception from `main`, by the way). Either return a value, if you can a meaningful one – or (probably better) change return type to `void`.

Comment: Now discovering the true problem: You only ever scan the choice *once* – before entering the loop – in consequence your `switch` statement will always check exactly the same choice from before. You need to move scanning the choice *into* the loop!

Comment: In addition to the globals mentioned above: `ch` and `item` should neither be globals nor struct members, instead *local* variables of the functions they use them (i.e. `main` and `push`).

Comment: Yet another (general) recommendation concerning re-usability: What, if you didn't want to read the variables from `stdin` any more, but instead from a socket? What, if that socket transported the data in binary format? With every such change you would need to modify your stack implementation. Better is separating input/output from the implementation of *whichever* tool (here the stack). Instead fetch input outside and pass it as another parameter to the implementation. A return value (either boolean or error code semantics) would allow to print an error message *outside* of the function.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for pointing out the mistakes. Now the program gives output correctly.

Comment: As an example to my previous comment (too slow in typing ;) – you need to include `stdbool.h`  for using `bool`): `bool push(struct stack* s, int v) { bool success = s->size < s->capacity); if(success) {  s->data[s->size++] = v; } return success; }` – you still can wrap this into *another* function that *does* read input: `void getAndPush(struct stack* s) { int v; if(scanf(...) != 1) { /* TODO: illegal input!!! */ } else if(!push(s, v) { /* print error message */ } /* else all went fine */ }` – getting original functionality back while retaining the re-usability of the list implementation...

Comment: Note: Above example includes all the recommendations given previously as well! Note, too, that you should always check the return value of `scanf` as in my example to catch illegal input.

Comment: @Aconcagua I skipped structure to keep the program simple

Answer (score 0):

The program read the choice from users outside the while loop and hence program reads `ch` value once. Therefore, the `switch` statement checks only one `ch` value. The program should read `ch` value inside the while loop.

```
while (1)
    
{  
        printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
        
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        switch (ch) 
        {
            case 1:
            push (stack);
            break;
            case 2:
            pop (stack);
            break;
            case 3:
            display (stack);
            break;
            case 4:
            exit(1);
            break;
            default:
            printf("\nError! please select correct option");
        
        }
    }
```